# Error: Help D: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, system

Code here ._.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt");
        file.WriteLine();
        file.Close();
        int userType = 0;
        System.IO.StreamReader fileUsername =
            new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt");
        file.Close();
        string retrievedUsername = fileUsername.ReadToEnd();
        file.Close();



        Console.WriteLine("Please note that this is a prototype, passwords are not hashed/encrypted ^_^");
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the meData service! Ver. 0.01 Beta, made by mechron");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your username below or type register to register a new account on this device");
        string loginUsername = Console.ReadLine();
      if (loginUsername == retrievedUsername)
   {

          Console.WriteLine("Welcome back user!");
           userType = 1;
   }
      else
      {
          if (loginUsername == "register")
          {

              Console.WriteLine("Choose your username!");
              string registeredUsername = Console.ReadLine();
              System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt");
              file.WriteLine(registeredUsername);
              file.Close();
          }
          else
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Error, command not recognized");}

      }


   }


    }
}
```

My code above ^*^ Erm... well... I'm having trouble with this.... System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process keeps popping up when I hit this line System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Public\Usernames.txt");
;*;
Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code does not close the reader - it closes the writer *again*. Even if it worked it would close the reader before you actually read.

```
System.IO.StreamReader fileUsername = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt");
file.Close();
string retrievedUsername = fileUsername.ReadToEnd();
file.Close();
```

You should make your code look like this:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt"))
{
    file.WriteLine();
}

int userType = 0;
string retrievedUsername = String.Empty;

using (System.IO.StreamReader fileUsername = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt"))
{
    retrievedUsername = fileUsername.ReadToEnd();
}
```

---

The code that follows is also flawed:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt");
file.WriteLine(registeredUsername);
file.Close();
```

See the error? You're opening (and not closing!!) a `StreamWriter` called `files`, but you're trying to write and trying to close `file`. Big mistake.

This can also be fixed like this:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt"))
{
    files.WriteLine(registeredUsername);
}
```

Comment: One more problem, *Sweats, after a few lines it says file is not referenced in current context. I'm guessing this relates to the fact I have to declare it outside using? Sorry for these nooby questions ^_^

Comment: The `file` variable is only valid in the block that belongs to the `using` statement. See the edit I'm making right now...

Answer (score 0):

You never close the `StreamReader` object `fileUsername`.  You can call [`fileUsername.Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after you have finished reading the file, however it would be better to use a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

```
 using (StreamReader fileUserName = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt")) 
 {

 }
```

That way the object is closed properly after it has finished its operations.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed `StreamReader` object called `fileUsername`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt");
        file.WriteLine();
        file.Close();
        int userType = 0;
        System.IO.StreamReader fileUsername =
            new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt");
        file.Close();
        string retrievedUsername = fileUsername.ReadToEnd();
        file.Close();
        fileUsername.Close();// <--- This line



        Console.WriteLine("Please note that this is a prototype, passwords are not hashed/encrypted ^_^");
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the meData service! Ver. 0.01 Beta, made by mechron");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your username below or type register to register a new account on this device");
        string loginUsername = Console.ReadLine();
      if (loginUsername == retrievedUsername)
   {

          Console.WriteLine("Welcome back user!");
           userType = 1;
   }
      else
      {
          if (loginUsername == "register")
          {

              Console.WriteLine("Choose your username!");
              string registeredUsername = Console.ReadLine();
              System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt");
              file.WriteLine(registeredUsername);
              file.Close();
          }
          else
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Error, command not recognized");}

      }


   }
```

Comment: You could have fixed the double `file.Close()` as well two lines above your `// <--- This line` comment.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the closing of fileUsername `StreamReader` , but I would change the code as below

```
string loginUsername = Console.ReadLine();
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
if(readText==loginUsername)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Welcome back user!");
}else if(loginUsername == "register")
{

   Console.WriteLine("Choose your username!");
   string registeredUsername = Console.ReadLine();
   File.WriteAllText(path,registeredUsername);
}
```